# SQL Inner Join Won't Select Data on Live server

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I'm having a massive issue with a **`SELECT`** statement using multiple **`INNER JOINS`**, I'm wondering whether i'm being really silly with my syntax or not!

Here's the SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.ID FROM Users INNER JOIN File ON Users.ID=File.ID 
INNER JOIN Purchased ON File.ObjectID= Purchased.ObjectID
```

The Users table contains the id:

```
1234
```

The File Table contains an id of:

```
1234
```

It also contains an ObjectID of:

```
4567
```

The purchased table contains the ObjectID of:

```
4567
```

The problem only seems to occur on the live server, on the local server this query works fine!

Comment: . . Personally, I find the `Users.Id = Files.Id` to be suspicious.  I might expect something like `Users.UserId = Files.UserId`, for instance.  Also, does the query return an error on the second system?  Are the data types the same in the tables?  Are you successfully connecting to the second system?

Comment: There are no errors, everything is exactly the same, and the connection is good! Is 'File' a reserved keyword?

Comment: . . If you mis-used a reserved word, then it would affect both systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sneaky space character was being included in my insert statements in 2 tables not the 3rd table, meaning that no rows would ever be selected!

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax looks fine.  If it "works" on your "local server" but does not work on your "live server" (whatever that means), the tables on the two environments must be different.